# go-restful + JWT authentication

Tags: rest, go, jwt, jwt-go, go-restful

I'm trying to plug JWT authentication within a very simple go service written with [go-restful](http://github.com/emicklei/go-restful).

The code is very similar to:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/emicklei/go-restful"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type User struct {
    Id, Name string
}

type UserList struct {
    Users []User
}

func getAllUsers(request *restful.Request, response *restful.Response) {
    log.Printf("getAllUsers")
    response.WriteEntity(UserList{[]User{{"42", "Gandalf"}, {"3.14", "Pi"}}})
}

func NewUserService() *restful.WebService {
    ws := new(restful.WebService)
    ws.
        Path("/users").
        Consumes(restful.MIME_XML, restful.MIME_JSON).
        Produces(restful.MIME_JSON, restful.MIME_XML)

    ws.Route(ws.GET("").To(getAllUsers))

    return ws
}


func main() {
    restful.Add(NewUserService())
    log.Printf("start listening on localhost:8080")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

where `restful.Request` is a wrapper around `http.Request`.

That being said, it might be possible to use the [Auth0 jwt middleware](https://github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware).

But as a golang newbie, I'm a bit lost in the plumbing process. I see that I must use a `Filter` function like

```
ws.Filter(jwtAuthentication)
```

where

```
func jwtAuthentication(req *restful.Request, resp *restful.Response, chain *restful.FilterChain) {
    // Jwt Magic goes here \o
    chain.ProcessFilter(req, resp)
}
```

But I don't figure how and where should I instanciate the JWT middleware.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example of filter implementation using [auth0/go-jwt-middleware](https://github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware). In real life you probably want to avoid creating new instance of `jwtMiddleware` every time.

```
func jwtAuthentication(req *restful.Request, resp *restful.Response, chain *restful.FilterChain) {
    jwtMiddleware := jwtmiddleware.New(jwtmiddleware.Options{
        ValidationKeyGetter: func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            return []byte("My Secret"), nil
        },
        SigningMethod: jwt.SigningMethodHS256,
    })

    if err := jwtMiddleware.CheckJWT(resp.ResponseWriter, req.Request); err != nil {
        logger.Errorf("Authentication error: %v", err)
    }
    chain.ProcessFilter(req, resp)
}
```

After the filter the parsed token will be in the context ([auth0/go-jwt-middleware](https://github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware) uses [gorilla/context](https://github.com/gorilla/context)). Default context key is `user`.

Note: when `JWTMiddleware.SigningMethod` is set, the middleware verifies that tokens are signed with the specific signing algorithm.

If the signing method is not constant, the `ValidationKeyGetter` callback can be used to implement additional checks.

Important to avoid security issues described [here](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/03/31/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of Login API to generate Token, and JWT Authentication filter to check authentication

```
import (
  "os"
  "strings"
  "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
  "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

type Token struct {
  UserId   uint
  Username string
  jwt.StandardClaims
}

type Account struct {
  ID       uint
  Email    string
  Password string
  Token    string
}

func Login(request *restful.Request, response *restful.Response) {
  account := &Account{ID: 1, Email: "test@email.com" }
  // TODO - account should be pulled from database

  tk := &Token{ UserId: account.ID }
  token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.GetSigningMethod("HS256"), tk)
  tokenString, _ := token.SignedString([]byte("JWT-SECRET-GOES-RIGHT-HERE"))
  account.Token = tokenString
  account.Password = ''
  response.WriteEntity(account)
}

func JwtAuthentication(req *restful.Request, resp *restful.Response, chain *restful.FilterChain) {
    tokenHeader := req.Request.HeaderParameter("Authorization")

    if tokenHeader == "" {
      resp.WriteErrorString(http.StatusForbidden, "Not Authorized")
      return
    }

    splitted := strings.Split(tokenHeader, " ")
    if len(splitted) != 2 {
      resp.WriteErrorString(http.StatusForbidden, "Not Authorized")
      return
    }

    tokenPart := splitted[1]
    tk := &Token{}

    token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenPart, tk, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
      return []byte("JWT-SECRET-GOES-RIGHT-HERE"), nil
    })

    if err != nil { //Malformed token, returns with http code 403 as usual
      resp.WriteErrorString(http.StatusForbidden, "Not Authorized")
      return
    }

    if !token.Valid { //Token is invalid, maybe not signed on this server
      resp.WriteErrorString(http.StatusForbidden, "Not Authorized")
      return
    }

    chain.ProcessFilter(req, resp)
}
```

And then apply filter

```
ws.Filter(JwtAuthentication)
```